# SQLite 3.8.2 exception on Update statement

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I just updated my Windows Phone 8 project to use the latest version of SQLite.  I made sure to update the sqlite-net-wp8 package as well to use the latest version.

Now when I execute an update statement, I get an exception from the db: SQL logic error or missing database

This worked fine with 3.8.1.  Is there any way I can go back?

Comment: I did find the old version download (www.sqlite.org/2013/sqlite-wp80-winrt-3080100.vsix).  You just need to uninstall the old one first to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you try uninstall the old version to use it and the problem persist, maybe you can fix this looking at your Query...

After googling with an old bug that I've fixed before, I found this ...

> SQLite3::SQLException: SQL logic error or missing database
>   After usual googling around and trying to fix it I just saw what the problem with the Query is.

Comment: Reverting back to 3.8.1 seems to fix my issue.  I am using the sqlite-net-wp8 and sqlite-net packages in my code.  The exception occurs when I just run connection.Update(object).  The insert worked fine.  Have you seen an issue with 3.8.2?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I thought it may be due to the sqlite-net-wp8 package using 3.8.1 so I updated it to 3.8.2 - seems to have made no difference.

Comment: Oh and it happens on an insert statement for me.

Comment: You guys aren't first to complain about the version 3.8.2, it seems is full of bugs! Try just use SQLite 3.8.1 until those errors be fixed.

Comment: That said 3.8.2 works fine for me on Windows 8.1, it's just Windows Phone I have issues on.

Comment: New version of SQLite for Windows Phone is out, but it seems it is once again not working properly. Can you confirm this?