# SQLite on Windows Phone problems

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a SQLite-heavy Windows Phone 8 application and tried to use the latest version, which however seems extremely buggy and randomly fails during INSERT and UPDATE statements with zero-explanation errors (see [SQLite 3.8.2 exception on Update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474253/sqlite-3-8-2-exception-on-update-statement)). For that reason I removed the latest version from the project and entered the one that works correctly.
I published the app to Windows Phone Store after rigorous testing, everything working correctly. However, when it came out, the errors that happened when the newer version was there are happening again. I tested the exact same Release build XAP on my device (via the Deploy tool), and it works perfectly. But after I download the app from Store, once again I get the same issues.

Has someone a way to explain these problems? I repeat, that the exact same XAP that I uploaded I tested and it is working.

EDIT: Additional note - the problems are really random - the same INSERT once works and doesn't another time, although data are valid...

Thank you very much, I'm quite desperate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of SQLite (3.8.3.1) that was released on 11th April 2014 should resolve any issues, finally :-) . So far I have not encountered the same error again so I suppose it is now fixed.

http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3_1.html