# Error in update: "logic error or missing database" sqlitepcl

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-net, sqlite.net

I can not get two updates in the same transaction.

The first is performed but the second error.

When making the second update I get the error: "logic error or missing database"

The following example:

```
string sql = "UPDATE PARAMETROFILIAL SET VALOR = ?, DESCRICAO = ? WHERE IDPARAMETROFILIAL = ?";
            using (SQConnectionDatabase sqCon = new SQConnectionDatabase(MobileContext.Instance.databasePath))
            {
                    sqCon.BeginTransaction();
                    int result = sqCon.Execute(sql, "X1", "X1", 1);
                    result = sqCon.Execute(sql, "X2", "X2", 2);
                    sqCon.Commit();
            }
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had to perform the downgrade to version www.sqlite.org/2013/sqlite-wp80-winrt-3080100.vsi

[SQLite 3.8.2 exception on Update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474253/sqlite-3-8-2-exception-on-update-statement)